# AngularJs: Applying ng-class for input element in a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to enhance our directive. It used to be one input type='submit' class="btn" element and the directive had replace: "true". I've changed the template for this directive to the following:

```html
<input type="submit" value="{{value}}" id="btnChoose"
       ng-class="{{ngClass}}"
       style="width: 85% !important; margin-top: 0;"
       class="btn_file_select" ng-click="click()" />
```

(Showing top part of HTML). I changed replace to false and added ngClass: '@' to the directive.

In my form I set ng-class to something and I can see it set when I inspect the element using Dev. Tools. I can also see that same ng-class expression added to my button. However, it doesn't work and it's not being evaluated.

How should I properly update my directive to be able to receive the ng-class property on the parent's div in the form and pass it to my button?

Sample of using this directive in a form right now:

```html
<data-desc:type ng-class="{greenText: (currentSalespoint['lRemoteS' + n] == 0 && metaData.layOuts['dlrs' + n] > 0)}"
    title="{{ '@String.Format(Labels.selectX, Labels.printer)'}}"
    do-search="popup()"
    value="{{currentSalespoint['lRemoteS'+ n] == 0 ? (metaData.layOuts['dlrs' + n]==0?'@String.Format(Labels.selectX, Labels.printer)':metaData.layOuts['dlrs' + n + 'Text']) : currentSalespoint['lRemoteS'+ n + 'Text']}}"
    param="layouts"
    filter-by="Remote Printer"
    message="@String.Format(Labels.selectX, Labels.printer)"
    selected="currentSalespoint['lRemoteS'+ n]" descrip-value="descrip" type-value="'lRemoteS'+ n"
    description="currentSalespoint['lRemoteS'+ n 

    + 'Text']"></data-desc:type>
```

and the directive currently has the following at the top:

```js
return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            replace: false,

            scope: {
                title: '@',
                message: '@',
                param: '@',
                selected: '=',
                description: '=',
                value: '@',
                descrip: '=',
                type: '=',
                ngClass: '@',
                doSearch: '&',
                filterBy: '@?'
            },
```

Comment: Can you show a code sample of your directive?

Comment: I edited my current post to show sample of current usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the "@" to "=" and change `ng-class="{{something}}"` to `ng-class="something"`, and don't use `ngClass` as the name of the scope property.

Embedding interpolated values inside of expressions is considered bad practice per this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#known-issues

Comment: It means I would have to adjust all HTMLs that currently use this directive to use this new property, right? I was hoping for some way around. I'll try it since I think only 2 pages currently use ng-class with this directive

Comment: So, do I understand you correctly as you suggest, say, dynamicClass property. My directive will have dynamicClass: ='' and in the form I'll copy current ng-class to this dynamic-class and in the template for directive I'll have ng-class="dynamicClass" ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes. You'll pass the expression _through_ your directive's scope property bound as `dynamicClass: '='` to the `ng-class="dynamicClass"` in its template. On the element that the directive is specified you'll also specify `dynamic-class="expression"`. As long as it's a valid expression it should work. You can't use `ngClass` as the scope property because a directive with that name already exists.

Comment: While you were typing your comment I tried your suggestion and it worked. I now need to verify it works when I don't set this property in HTML.

Comment: If I don't set dynamic-class property then I get [Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'dynamicClass' used with directive 'descType' is non-assignable!] I'll try dynamicClass: '=?' and see if it helps. UPDATE. It did help and now it works.

Comment: That should work. See this for more info on what will and won't work: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign